# Placing text at random positions on the screen in beamer

Tags: beamer, positioning, color, fontsize, characters

I am creating a presentation and for the Q&A session slide, I want to show question marks (?) in various colors and sizes in random locations on the screen.

Is this possible in `beamer`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, with `beamer` and `tikz` it is:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=rgb]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Questions}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,30} {
      \pgfmathparse{rnd}
      \definecolor{MyColor}{hsb}{\pgfmathresult,1,1}
      \pgfmathparse{3.0*rnd+1.0}
      \node[text=MyColor] at (8*rnd,6*rnd) {\scalebox{\pgfmathresult}{?}};
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here's the result:

[image]