# Text collage (word cloud) in LaTeX?

Tags: color, rotating, automation

There are some **automatic** method (package, class, macro) in LaTeX to do a text collage similar to that showed in the image?

[image: MWE]

If not, is would be possible without too much manual work?. The background, the font and the shape of the collage does not matter (is enough a rentangular shape).

Comment: I don't think someone has implemented a word cloud engine in TeX, yet. Maybe you have more luck searching for Lua libraries which could be leveraged. Here's a blog post which uses a Java word cloud engine which can be hooked into TeX: [Word clouds in ConTeXt](https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2010/08/03/word-clouds-in-context/)

Comment: For anyone trying to implement this, here's the algorithm wordle uses: [Here's how Wordle actually works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1478314/1013470)

Comment: sort of related (possible starting point): [Placing text at random positions on the screen in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100049). I also added `word clouds` to the title- hope that's ok :)

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Wordle-like word clouds](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/917/5245), [Word clouds in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26559/5245)

Comment: The right words were finally  "word clouds", so the question is really a duplicate. But I asked specifically for a LaTeX solution, that is not still answered in Marco's links. Although only related, for me only the cmhughes's link is in the right direction.