# Is possible get this image with tikz and random?

Tags: tikz-pgf, random

I don't know if is possible draw a picture like the next with tikz and some random related command:

[image]

Comment: Yes. It is possible. That is, it is just boxes of text in different sizes and colours at different angles. So you could, if you really wanted, recreate it. No idea why you would want to do that, but it seems a relatively harmless project as these things go.

Comment: you have to do a lot of calculations because the textboxes do not intersect. tikz is not the right tool here.

Comment: A little bit related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180510

Comment: You can also look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146178/1952

Comment: Related: [Wordle-like word clouds](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/917/5764); [Text collage (word cloud) in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135462/5764)

Answer (score 3):

Basically, yes, you could do this. However, you could not do it automatically or randomly because it requires the programme take account of the shapes of the glyphs, which TeX knows nothing about. To TeX, everything is just a box. It neither knows or cares what is in the boxes. But this kind of word cloud requires things to be slotted together in ways which are sensitive to the shapes of the characters and not just to the size, location and rotation of the boxes containing them.

That is, it would be bonkers to try doing this in TikZ. Like trying to use a rose petal to bail out a sinking ocean liner. Best not to try.